# Why Laravel/Ardent is not saving data into database after save()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ardent

Here's my Laravel/Ardent Model.
I'm using auto-hydration.

```
class Party extends \LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent {

public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;
public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true;
protected $guarded = array();

protected $table = 'Parties';
public $timestamps = true;

use SoftDeletingTrait;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
public static $rules = array(
   ...
);
public static $relationsData = array(...);
```

My controller code

```
public function postCreate()
{
    $party = new Party;
    $saveSuccess = $party->save();
    if($saveSuccess)
    {
    return Response::json([
            'status' => $saveSuccess
        ],
        200
    );
    }
}
```

It is NOT throwing ANY error or exception. But data is not getting saved either. What could be the reason?

Comment: `$party` is unmodified when you are calling `save()` on it. Do any of your validation rules have required fields?

Comment: Yes, I have 'required' validations set.
But I thought as Ardent is doing auto-hydration, I don't need to explicitly modify it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I missed the Ardent part for some reason. I still think it is not passing validation though. Or, you haven't specified $fillable fields array().

Comment: Try posting your validation rules